# How to get Firestore GeoPoint value in nested Object?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Here is my temporary code for generate geopoint datatype from Firestore DB

```
firestoreDb.collection("products").document(productId).get()
  .addOnSuccessListener(documentSnapshot -> {
     Products products = documentSnapshot.toObject(Products.class); 
     countryCode = Objects.requireNonNull(products.getAddress().get("countryCode")).toString();

     String stringGeoPoint = products.getLocation().get("geoPoint").toString();
     System.out.println(stringGeoPoint);
     //Output: GeoPoint { latitude=29.339555, longitude=169.715858 }

     GeoPoint geoPoint = documentSnapshot.getGeoPoint(stringGeoPoint);// ?
     //Output: null
  }
```

Products.class

```
public class Products{ 
   public Map<String, Object> address;
   public Map<String, Object> location;

   public Map<String, Object> getAddress(){return address;}
   public Map<String, Object> getLocation(){return location;}
}
```

My Firestore Structure

[image]

- Products
- -->{productIds}
- ------>title (String)
- ------>location (map)
- ---------->geoPoint (GeoPoint)
- ------>address (map)
- ---------->countryCode (String)

Comment: Instead of describing how you database looks like, please add a screenshot of it.

Comment: edited, adding screenshot.

Comment: `Location` is array of data.

Comment: @LatiefAnwar So you want to get the value of `geoPoint` property that exist within `location`, right? Please also add the content of your `Products` class and responde with @AlexMamo

Answer (score 3):

You post two different code and one of them provides you proper answer :

```
String stringGeoPoint = products.getLocation().get("geoPoint").toString();
```

and this line of code shows null :

```
GeoPoint geoPoint = documentSnapshot.getGeoPoint(stringGeoPoint);
```

**Reason :**

The reason behind the first code works properly because when you retrieving data you have created data model for the documents field. you have you method as `getLocation()` which will return the Location array. Then you can normally look into hashmap array by passing the key of hashmap

Location is an Array of `Hashmap<String, String>`.

So the 2nd code won't work for you cause there is no field under the documentSnapshot.